# Why I cant debug qml from qt creator?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

I installed the last Qt 5.12.2 . Then I open the cmake project via Qt Creator.

First I see a huge count on the intellisence issues: from "udeclared identifies of nullptr" to errors with each type "unknown type name".

The build proceeded successfully and I receive correct binary.

But any breakpoint marked as "Unclaimed breakpoint" and I cant debug any .qml (the .cpp could be debug)

So why it happens and how to debug the QML? (this future is still supported?)

**UPDATE**: The "QQmlDebuggingEnabler enabler;" and "doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html" doesnt helps :(

**UPDATE2**: @Amfasis -

[image]

Comment: what you need to know about QML debugging can be found here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html

Comment: I don't see it in the doc referenced by `bardao`, but I had to put a `QQmlDebuggingEnabler enabler;` line in main.cpp

Comment: @Amfasis the only way I know of to debug QML is with javascript. Place `console.debug()` pretty much anywhere you want and you will know which part of the code is reached. You will see the message in your application output

Comment: @bardao You can actually set breakpoints in your qml file in qt creator, if configured correctly, execution will pause there and you can see all javascript variables :-)

Comment: @AeroSun did you also enable QML debugging in the run tab of your project? (and perhaps read the stated prerequisites?)

Comment: @Amfasis on my side the debugger dont stop on the qml breakpoint :( How to enable QML debugging? It is not turn on by default?

Comment: @AeroSun where did you put your breakpoint (can you show some code)? I can imagine it will not stop everywhere, but it's hard to tell without example

Comment: chances are you're not reaching that breakpoint to begin with, Maybe your `onClicked` event isn't being called. `console.debug("clicked")` and see if that's working first

Comment: @bardao, onClicked works - it loads other data - I see that it works. It is just a example - this issue present with each function

Answer (score 1):

I created a CMake-based Qt Quick project, and it shown that it supports QML/JS debugging. I checked the CMakeLists.txt, and found one relevant line:

```
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
```

So I think if you'd like to debug your CMake-based Qt Quick project, you should also add this line to your CMakeLists.txt.

And don't forget to check on enable QML in the project setting within the sector of debugging setting.